# The bound $\prod\limits_{i=0}^ju_i<\alpha_j<\prod\limits_{i=0}^j(u_i+1)$ not correct?

Tags: number-theory, induction, continued-fractions, quadratic-integer-rings

In [Distribution of class numbers in continued fraction families of real quadratic fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.02424)

Lemma 8 says

> let $\omega_d=[u_0,\overline{u_1,u_2,\dots ,u_{s-1},u_s}]$ (note: only re-specified in the [published version](https://search.proquest.com/openview/2f3ec3e75ce227b10865bef3c94176fb/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=41713))
> $$\prod\limits_{i=0}^ju_i<\alpha_j<\prod\limits_{i=0}^j(u_i+1)$$
>
> "The proof easily follows by induction from the recurrence $\alpha_{i+1}=u_{i+1}\alpha_i+\alpha_{i-1}$"

Note: $\omega_d=\sqrt d$ (page 6), $\alpha_{-1}=1$ and $\alpha_i=p_i+q_i\sqrt d$ with $\frac{p_i}{q_i}=[u_0,u_1,...,u_i]$

Now if I take $\sqrt {71}=[8,\overline{2,2,1,7,1,2,2,16}]$, the **RHS** does not seem to hold for the first few $j$

e.g. with $j=1$ we have $16<33.8523<27$

Is there something I missed? Or is there a typo in the paper?

Even the "easy induction" first step does not seem right:
$u_0<u_0+\sqrt d<u_0+1$

Thanks

---

EDIT: I suspect that this is only true for purely periodic continued fractions.

In this case $\omega_d=[\overline{2a_0,u_1,\dots ,u_{s-1}}]=\sqrt d+a_0$

$-\overline{\omega_d}=\sqrt d-a_0$ and $\alpha_i=p_i+q_i(\sqrt d-a_0)$

In this scenario, the bounds and the induction (starting with $2a_0<a_0+\sqrt d<2a_0+1$) seem to be right